# how do you put before filters in modular controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have several controllers that are in a module:

```
class SoapTest::DashboardController < ApplicationController

class SoapTest::TestCasesController < ApplicationController
```

etc.

I want to be able to check if a user has certain permissions for a module, and since I don't have a "parent" controller where the above ones inherit, i thought to put the check in a before filter in applications. But I can't seem to get the module name:

in application controller, i have:

```
before_filter :check_company_features

def check_company_features
  puts controller_name
end
```

but controller_name just returns "dashboard". I need to get the "SoapTest" clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be attention, what you currently call `modules` actually are `namespaces`.

The reason why `controller_name` returns only the class name (and not the fully qualified name) is because Rails explicitly strips the namespaces. You can get them by calling the Ruby `#name` method on the controller class.

```
class SoapTest::DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_company_features

  def check_company_features
    puts controller_name
    # => "dashboard_controller"
    puts self.class.name
    # => "SoapTest::DashboardController"
  end 
end
```

There are several String inflection methods you can call on the `#name` to get the formatted version.

However, I strongly encourage you to use a namespaced main controller.
Instead of using

```
class SoapTest::DashboardController < ApplicationController
```

you can extend a `SoapTest::ApplicationController`

```
class SoapTest::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_company_features

  def check_company_features
    # ...
  end
end

class SoapTest::DashboardController < SoapTest::ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: will this soaptestapplication controller reside in the same directory as its children? so controllers/soap_test/soap_test_application_controller.rb? also is it okay to have one extra controller that you wouldn't use except for inheritance?

Comment: Yes is the answer to both questions.

Comment: crap, i just realized 2 out of 3 controllers inherit from inheritedresources. the other one inherits from application. will i be creating 2 base controllers?

Comment: Ruby is class oriented. If you really need a class, create the class.

Comment: thanks man, i actually found out how to use inheritedresources wthout actually inheriting from it. great help!